# How to pass a comma separated input parameters in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, parameters

Hi I need to create a get stored procedure, which will use two input parameters. One is CustomerId and the other is ProductId. and for ProductId, it needs to be a input parameter with comma separated. I know I can do that with table value parameter, but how to pass that with comma separated input parameter.

Here is the select query:

```
SELECT CustomerId, ProductId FROM TABLE1
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetCustomColumn
@CustomerId int,
@ProductId dbo.ttProductId READONLY
```

But I don't know how to do next, like convert table type into comma separated, and how to write the where clause like:

```
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId OR @CustomerId IS NULL
```

Comment: you can join with table valued parameter, instead of generating comma seperated list and using IN clause

Comment: But I need to use that by request.